# Move Files to Files with old extension in same directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a question after the errors I am getting for an assignment as it seems to work on my own tests. I will post the script and the errors below.
Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1
do $file | grep \.old$ > /dev/null
 if [ "$file" != 0 ]
then mv $file $file.old
else $file
fi
done

Files created in 'testdir:

file1  file2.old  file3old  file4.old

Execution of 'oldfiles testdir':


'oldfiles testdir' incorrectly produced some output or errors:
for file in $1
  do $file | grep \.old$ > /dev/null
  if [ "$file" != 0 ]
    then mv $file $file.old
  else $file
  fi
done
+ for file in '$1'
+ grep '.old$'
+ /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir
/home/npkrause/scripts/oldfiles: line 4: /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir: Is a directory
+ '[' /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir '!=' 0 ']'
+ mv /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir.old

Files in 'testdir' after 'oldfiles' was run:
ls: cannot access /var/tmp/uli101.npkrause.assign4.8938.testdir: No such file or directory

Filenames don't seem to be correct

Please hit <Enter> to continue with the Assignment
```

Comment: What's the script supposed to do? You've not told us enough to work out what "seems to work" means or what tests you've tried.

Comment: You can't execute a file or directory which is what `$file | grep ...` is trying to do. You want to give the file to grep as an argument instead. `grep '\.old$' "$file"`.

Comment: You should run your script through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) and fix the warnings it reports and then try to figure out what your script is actually supposed to be doing since right now that isn't at all clear (or necessarily even sane).

Comment: If the question is "how do I check whether a filename ends with `.old`?", then that would be a much more succinct and useful title.

Comment: You will write a bash shell script called 'oldfiles' which takes one argument,the name of a directory, and adds the extension ".old" to all visible filesin the directory that don't already have it.  Treat subdirectories the sameas ordinary files.  For example:
$ ls
file1 file2.old file3old file4.old
$ oldfiles .
$ ls
file1.old file2.old file3old.old file4.old

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=$1
for file in "$dir"/* ; do
    [[ $file == *.old ]] || mv -- "$file" "$file.old"
done
```

Quote all uses of $dir and $file (except within double square brackets) to protect against spaces or metacharacters in names.

Use 'mv --' to protect against directory names beginning with '-'.